# What is the purpose of the composite flow(from Sink and Source)?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I am trying the understand composite flow (from Sink and Source) from the [website](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stream-composition.html) and they represent as the following:

[image]

Could someone please provide an example for the usage of composite flow.
And when should I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Flow.fromSinkAndSource](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.22/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow$.html#fromSinkAndSource[I,O](sink:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SinkShape[I],_],source:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[O],_]):akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[I,O,akka.NotUsed]) provides a convenient way to assemble a `flow` composed with a `sink` as its input and a `source` as its output that are not connected, which can be best illustrated with the following diagram (available in the API link):

```
  +----------------------------------------------+
  | Resulting Flow[I, O, NotUsed]                |
  |                                              |
  |  +---------+                  +-----------+  |
  |  |         |                  |           |  |
I ~~>| Sink[I] | [no-connection!] | Source[O] | ~~> O
  |  |         |                  |           |  |
  |  +---------+                  +-----------+  |
  +----------------------------------------------+
```

As shown in @gabrielgiussi's answer, it's often used in cases where one wants to "switch" the output of an existing `source`( or `flow`) to some different output - for testing purposes or what-not.  Here's a trivialized example:

```scala
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val switchFlow = Flow.fromSinkAndSource( Sink.ignore, Source(List("a", "b", "c")) )

Source(1 to 5).via(switchFlow).runForeach(println)
// res1: scala.concurrent.Future[akka.Done] = Future(Success(Done))
// a
// b
// c
```

It's also worth noting that the method's "Mat" version, [fromSinkAndSourceMat](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.22/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow$.html#fromSinkAndSourceMat[I,O,M1,M2,M](sink:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SinkShape[I],M1],source:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[O],M2])(combine:(M1,M2)=%3EM):akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[I,O,M]), has some interesting use cases.  An example is to use it to keep `half-closed` WebSockets open by using `Source.maybe[T]` to maintain a `Promise[Option[T]]` as the materialized value which will be completed when one wants to close the connection.  Below is the sample code from the relevant section in the [Akka-http WebSockets client support](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html#half-closed-client-websockets) document:

```scala
// using Source.maybe materializes into a promise
// which will allow us to complete the source later
val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Promise[Option[Message]]] =
  Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(
    Sink.foreach[Message](println),
    Source.maybe[Message])(Keep.right)

val (upgradeResponse, promise) =
  Http().singleWebSocketRequest(
    WebSocketRequest("ws://example.com:8080/some/path"),
    flow)

// at some later time we want to disconnect
promise.success(None)
```

Comment: The first example, that you have provided, I understand the purpose of `Flow.fromSinkAndSource`. But on the second example with websocket, I do not get it. 
Look at the example again: `Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(Sink.foreach[Message](println),Source.maybe[Message])(Keep.right)`. The `Source.maybe[Message]` will send 
the data to webserver via websocket and `Sink.foreach[Message](println)` consumes messages. How can it be, that it consumes first with `Sink`, before the messages is sent.

Comment: @zero_coding, it's an example of a WebSockets client handling `Half-closed WebSockets`.  `Sink.foreach[Message](println)` consumes messages from the server, not from `Source.maybe[Message]`.  If you read the `Akka-http WebSockets client support` link I provided, you'll see how the "Mat" version `fromSinkAndSourceMat` is able to do what the ordinary `fromSinkAndSource` couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in some scenario you just need to provide the Flow and for certain cases you need a NoOp Flow.
Then you could do

```
Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore,Source.empty)
```

Or ignore every element from the Source and use another one

```
Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore,Source.tick(1.second,1.second,"something"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got understanding from [here](https://akka-ja-2411-translated.netlify.app/scala/http/client-side/websocket-support.html)

```
object SingleWebSocketRequest {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {     

    // print each incoming strict text message
    val printSink: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreach {
        case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
          println(message.text)
      }
 
    val helloSource: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
      Source.single(TextMessage("hello world!"))
 
    // the Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach
    // and it is completed when the stream completes
    val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Future[Done]] =
      Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(printSink, helloSource)(Keep.left)
 
    // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
    // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
    // and closed is a Future[Done] representing the stream completion from above
    val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
      Http().singleWebSocketRequest(WebSocketRequest("ws://echo.websocket.org"), flow)
 
    val connected = upgradeResponse.map { upgrade =>
      // just like a regular http request we can access response status which is available via upgrade.response.status
      // status code 101 (Switching Protocols) indicates that server support WebSockets
      if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
        Done
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
      }
    }
 
    // in a real application you would not side effect here
    // and handle errors more carefully
    connected.onComplete(println)
    closed.foreach(_ => println("closed"))
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this in an actual situation, and it is convenient. Websocket is a two-way connection and Akka-HTTP WebSocket provides SingleWebSocketRequest function which takes a flow in argument and uses it in joinMat function as a parameter. With this configuration, your source plays a key role here to send a message to WebSocket and your sink is for receiving a message from WebSocket. So this is not just like:

Source ~> Sink

its is like

Other Source(WebSocket) ~> Sink

Other Source(WebSocket) <~ Source ( ex: ping message every 15 seconds)