# Does composite flow make loop?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to understand, how the following code snippet works:

```
val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Future[Done]] =
      Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(printSink, helloSource)(Keep.left)
```

Two guys gave a very wonderful explanation on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55669591/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-composite-flowfrom-sink-and-source/55672388?noredirect=1#comment98069487_55672388). I understand the concept of the Composite flow, but how does it work on the websocket client.

Consider the following code:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.{ Done, NotUsed }
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws._

import scala.concurrent.Future

object SingleWebSocketRequest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    import system.dispatcher

    // print each incoming strict text message
    val printSink: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreach {
        case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
          println(message.text)
      }

    val helloSource: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
      Source.single(TextMessage("hello world!"))

    // the Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach
    // and it is completed when the stream completes
    val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Future[Done]] =
      Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(printSink, helloSource)(Keep.left)

    // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
    // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
    // and closed is a Future[Done] representing the stream completion from above
    val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
      Http().singleWebSocketRequest(WebSocketRequest("ws://echo.websocket.org"), flow)

    val connected = upgradeResponse.map { upgrade =>
      // just like a regular http request we can access response status which is available via upgrade.response.status
      // status code 101 (Switching Protocols) indicates that server support WebSockets
      if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
        Done
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
      }
    }

    // in a real application you would not side effect here
    // and handle errors more carefully
    connected.onComplete(println)
    closed.foreach(_ => println("closed"))
  }
}
```

It is a websocket client, that send a message to the websocket server and the `printSink` receives it and print it out.

How can it be, that `printSink` receives messages, there is no a connection between the `Sink` and `Source`.

Is it like a loop?

[image]

Stream flow is from left to right, how it comes that the `Sink` can consume messages from websocket server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat` puts an independent `Sink` and a `Source` to a shape of the `Flow`. Elements going into that `Sink` do not end up at the `Source`.

From the Websocket client API perspective, it needs a `Source` from which requests will be sent to the server and a `Sink` that it will send the responses to. The `singleWebSocketRequest` could take a `Source` and a `Sink` separately, but that would be a bit more verbose API.

Here is a shorter example that demonstrates the same as in your code snippet but is [runnable](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/4gfDrzX/1), so you can play around with it:

```scala
import akka._
import akka.actor._
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

implicit val sys = ActorSystem()
implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

def openConnection(userFlow: Flow[String, String, NotUsed])(implicit mat: Materializer) = {
  val processor = Flow[String].map(_.toUpperCase)
  processor.join(userFlow).run()
}

val requests = Source(List("one", "two", "three"))
val responses = Sink.foreach(println)
val userFlow = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(responses, requests)

openConnection(userFlow)
```